# "no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String)"in arraylist constructor?

Tags: java, random, arraylist, constructor

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class College
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private ArrayList<Student> students;

    public College()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add("Student 1");
        students.add("Student 2");
        students.add("Student 3");

    }
}
```

basically it highlights the .add showing the error message "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive", I don't understand what I did wrong here? I looked at a lot of these kinds of problem threads here but I did exactly what they did

Comment: Add your `Student` class to your post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are adding `String`s to a `List` parametrized to take `Student`s.

Of course this is not going to compile.

- Add a constructor to your `Student` class, taking a `String` argument (and the relevant logic within).
- Then, use the following idiom: `students.add(new Student("Student 1"));`

To be noted, generics are there precisely to fail compilation at that stage.

If you had used a raw `List` (Java 4-style), your code would have compiled, but all sorts of evil would have happened at runtime, since you'd expect `Student` objects to be contained in your `List`, but you'd get `String`s instead.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the code of the Student class? Like others have said, you have a Student arraylist and are sending a String instead. That is an invalid argument.

If your Student class takes a string to be initialized, you can try:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
students.add(new Student("Student 1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList,  `private ArrayList<Student> students` can accept only `Student` objects.You are trying to add `String` to it.

If you want the list to accept String, define it like this: `private ArrayList<String> student`

Or, if you want the list to be of `Student` objects, then construct `Student` objects from the strings (*how* depends on the `Student` object) and add the object to list.

Comment: thank you i just realize what i did wrong now, thanks very much